# How to interpret CalibrateCamera perViewErrors?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

```cpp
Mat perViewErrors, stdDeviationsIntrinsics, stdDeviationsExtrinsics;
double error = calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points, img.size(), K, D, rvecs, tvecs, perViewErrors, perViewErrors, perViewErrors, flag);
```

The code runs fine, but the `perViewErrors` makes me very much confused. I have 24 pictures, but `perViewErrors` become a `Mat[144][1]`.

I searched a lot, but found no example about it. I find sources of this method (`opencv/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp`), but no help:

```cpp
            double viewErr = norm(_err, NORM_L2SQR);

            if( perViewErrors )
                perViewErrors->data.db[i] = std::sqrt(viewErr / ni);

            reprojErr += viewErr;
```

This the doc of `opencv#calibreateCamera`:
[image: doc]

How should I interpret this return value? what is per view?

Comment: [mre] please. "pattern view" shows up a few times in the docs for that function. check all the sizes/shapes of all the other arguments. I share your expectation but maybe one or your arguments is shaped wrong and causes this, or was shaped like that before you passed it in.

Comment: or maybe it _is_ a bug in opencv... show the contents of that array? are the first 24 values populated? are they all populated? consider "populated" to mean "sensible value", not uninitialized memory.